Add an image to an existing HDRI
I have an HDRI I am very happy with in a scene, but I want to add an image - specifically a moon - to the sky so that as the camera pans around my object the moon comes into view. I've rendered it out as a plane in the sky and the moon looks fantastic but does not retain its position relative to the sky.
I could try setting the moon a long way back and making it big, but I don't think that will work either.
What I want to do is add the moon as an image texture overlaying the HDRI in the world settings, but it doesn't work simply to do that. There is clearly some special sauce required. Is it possible and how?

The issue is similar to this: Add a panoramic background to scene in Cycles
However, I can't make the image equirectangular.

I think you could get a better result if you do this on a photo editing app.

I'm not sure I understand why "overlaying it over the HDRI doesn't work". You should be able to get an image of the moon and composite it over you sky fairly easy. Show us what you tried and maybe we can tell you why it isn't working.

Yes, I have thought about doing it GIMP or something, but it'll be a bit awkward and I'll have no control over the moon's placement.

"I'm not sure I understand why "overlaying it over the HDRI doesn't work"". The camera swings around quite a lot. The camera originally starts on the port side and swings around underneath. The Dirigible is also moving on a nurbs path and the camera tracked to the dirigible. Because the moon is not on the same plane as the HDRI, it doesn't move naturally as if it were part of the sky. Compositing an image of the moon over the HDRI  in the world shader area does not work. There must surely be a way to make it work.

The (partial) answer is to create an equirectangular image with alpha in an external editor such as gimp and bring the image in as an ENVIRONMENT TEXTURE, not as an image texture. You can then easily overlay the image on to the original HDRI and set up its own texture coordinates moving it around.
However, you won't be able to scale it and I am currently having problems trying to get GIMP to "map to object" in filters in order to map it to a sphere so that it does not distort when displayed as a world background. For some reason "map object..." is greyed out in GIMP and I am struggling to find a way around that.
But that is the solution I was looking for and I hope it helps some one else.

You could do this in two ways: either an object in the 3D scene, or an image node in compositing. I guess you did one of the two in order to get your current result.
3D Scene
In Blender 4.2, you can add an image mesh plane via the menu Add > Image > Mesh Plane. Before 4.2, you would have had to enable the addon Import Image As Planes, then use the menu Import > Image As Plane.
While browsing for the image to add, check your shader and alpha settings. If you don't want the image to be impacted by surrounding light and receive shadows, use shadeless or emit instead of Principled.

Then if you want your image to always face the camera, you can add a Track To constraint, targetting the camera object:

Then to have the image follow the camera as it moves, parent it to the camera. Select the image then ⇧ Shift select the camera and hit ⎈ CtrlP Set Parent To Object (Keep Transform).

Then you can move the camera around with the object following it, while being able to move it around yourself if needed.
Compositing
Using the compositor, you can add a mix node with alpha enabled, plug whatever your background is as first color input, and your image as second input. Then add a new mix node, plug your foreground as first color input, and your background + image as second colour input, and you might need to make your own factor to properly merge them.
Here i used the Environment pass as background (I used a nice Nishita Sky texture on the world shader), then reused the Env pass with a Greater Than math node to get the mask for the second mix node.


No, sorry. I am quite familiar with overlaying images and other movie images in the compositor as well as adding images in the 3D space. Neither of these will achieve what I am looking to do which is to overlay the moon in the WORLD environment. The issue is, that as the camera moves, the moons perspective in the camera needs to be the same as the rest of the HDRI image. I do indeed have the image in the 3D environment for this image and the planes Z access tracking the camera. But the moon moves around in relation to the HDRI image instead of being part of it.
